# How to create a graphical application shortcut in awesome WM?

Tags: awesome

How do I create a graphical shortcut to run a program in awesome WM? An icon I can click to launch a program?

Right now, I can only run Firefox by either:

- launching a terminal, then typing "`firefox &`",
- pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing `firefox`,
- editing config files to add a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @muru My question is for awesome WM specifically. The linked question is about Gnome.

Comment: Actually, the linked question is pretty much desktop or WM independent - `.desktop` format is part of the Free Desktop standard. But yes, that gnome tag shouldn't be there.

Comment: This answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/64237/158442, for example, cares nothing at all for the DE or WM

Comment: @muru Now, where do I put those .desktop files. I already have them in Unity, the only problem is where to put them for `awesome`.

Comment: awesome, being only a window manager, probably does nothing for the desktop. The desktop is usually handled by a file browser (Nautilus, nemo, etc) so you probably need to set your file browser to do so and put the launchers in your `~/Desktop` folder